# Wait for Room @Insert query completion

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I can't figure out how to do a "simple" operation with Room and MVVM pattern. 
I’m fetching some data with Retrofit. A “proper” response triggers an observer in the activity and a small part of the response itself is inserted in the database using Room library, wiping all previous values stored and inserting the fresh ones. Otherwise old values are retained on DB.
Just after that, I would like to check for a field in the database, but I’m not able to force this operation to wait until the previous one is completed.

Models

```
@Entity(tableName = "licence")
data class Licence(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "licence_id")
    var licenceId: Int = 0,
    @Ignore
    var config: List<LicenceConfig>? = null,
.......
//all the others attributes )

@Entity(foreignKeys = [
ForeignKey(
        entity = Licence::class,
        parentColumns = ["licence_id"],
        childColumns = ["licence_reference"],
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
)],tableName = "licence_configurations")
data class LicenceConfig(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "licence_config_id")
    var licenceConfigId: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name="licence_reference")
    var licenceReference: Int,
```

Observer in the activity

```
loginViewModel.apiResponse.observe(this, Observer { response ->
        response?.let {
             loginViewModel.insertLicences(response.licence)
        }
           //here I need to wait for the insertion to end
           loginViewModel.methodToCheckForTheFieldOnDatabase()
})
```

ViewModel

```
fun insertLicences(licences: List<Licence>) = viewModelScope.launch {
    roomRepository.deleteAllLicences()
    licences.forEach { licence ->
        roomRepository.insertLicence(licence).also { insertedLicenceId ->
            licence.config?.forEach { licenceConfiguration ->
                roomRepository.insertLicenceConfiguration(
                        licenceConfiguration.apply { licenceReference = insertedLicenceId.toInt() }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Room Repository

```
class RoomRepository(private val roomDao: RoomDao) {

val allLicences: LiveData<List<Licence>> = roomDao.getAllLicences()

suspend fun insertLicence(licence: Licence): Long {
   return roomDao.insertLicence(licence)
   }

suspend fun insertLicenceConfiguration(licenceConfiguration: LicenceConfig){
    return roomDao.insertLicenceConfiguration(LicenceConfig)
   }
}
```

RoomDao

```
@Dao
interface RoomDao {

@Query("select * from licence")
fun getAllLicences(): LiveData<List<Licence>>

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertLicence(licence: Licence): Long

@Insert
suspend fun insertLicenceConfiguration(licence: LicenceConfig)

@Query("DELETE FROM licence")
suspend fun deleteAllLicences()
}
```

Set an observer to the "allLicences" LiveData or directly on that field on DB is not an option because the operations will be performed just after the activity creation and I have to wait until the API response to perform them.

In another project, without Room, I have used async{} and .await() to perform sequential operations while working with coroutines but I can't really make it works here. When I pause the debugger just after the insertion method the value of "allLicences" it's always null but after resuming and exporting the DB the data are properly inserted. I also tried adding .invokeOnCompletion{} after the ViewModel method but with the same result.
Basically I would like to wait for this method to end to do another operation.

Any suggestions?

EDIT

I totally forgot to report the models! Each licence have a list of configurations. When I perform a licence insert I take the autogenerated id, I apply it to the licenceConfig and then I perform the insert for each licenceConfig object (the code in the nested forEach loop of the ViewModel method). The problem seems to be that performing this nested loop breaks the "synchronicity" of the operation

Answer (score 4):

To wait until insertion is completed, you need to move the coroutine creation from `insertLicences()` to your observer and also make the `insertLicences()` a suspend function.

---

```
loginViewModel.apiResponse.observe(this, Observer { response ->
    lifecycleScope.launch { 
        response?.let {
             loginViewModel.insertLicences(response.licence)
        }
        //here I need to wait for the insertion to end
        loginViewModel.methodToCheckForTheFieldOnDatabase()
    }
})
```

and

```
suspend fun insertLicences(licences: List<Licence>) {
    roomRepository.deleteAllLicences()
    licences.forEach { licence ->
        roomRepository.insertLicence(licence).also { insertedLicenceId ->
            licence.config?.forEach { licenceConfiguration ->
                roomRepository.insertLicenceConfiguration(
                    licenceConfiguration.apply { licenceReference = insertedLicenceId.toInt() }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

> Alternative Solution

You can shift all of the code present in the observer into ViewModel.

```
loginViewModel.apiResponse.observe(this, Observer { response ->
    loginViewModel.refreshLicenses(response)
})
```

and in ViewModel

```
fun refreshLicenses(response:Response?){
    viewModelScope.launch{
        response?.let {
            insertLicences(response.licence)
        }
        methodToCheckForTheFieldOnDatabase()
    }
}
```

and also make insertLicences as suspend function

```
suspend fun insertLicences(licences: List<Licence>) {
    roomRepository.deleteAllLicences()
    licences.forEach { licence ->
        roomRepository.insertLicence(licence).also { insertedLicenceId ->
            licence.config?.forEach { licenceConfiguration ->
                roomRepository.insertLicenceConfiguration(
                    licenceConfiguration.apply { licenceReference = insertedLicenceId.toInt() }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
I'm currently trying the "alternative" solution because it's the same one that I have successfully implemented in the other project. It still doesn't work but I have found the problem. If i leave only roomRepository.insertLicence(licence) the check method will not be executed until the completion of the first one ( I have added 5 seconds delay after the forEach to be sure). So the problem seems to be the nested insert of all the licenceConfigurations wich "break the flow". I have edited the answer with more informations

Comment: (5) statement aborts at 2: [PRAGMA journal_mode=PERSIST]

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Didn't read your conclusion before I reply but, I still think that your answer lies in coroutines

Using callbacks or promises, won't your function be executed when the insert query is finished?

> **Callbacks**
>
> With callbacks, the idea is to pass one function as a parameter to
>   another function, and have this one invoked once the process has
>   completed.

```
fun postItem(item: Item) {
    preparePostAsync { token -> 
        submitPostAsync(token, item) { post -> 
            processPost(post)
        }
    }
}

fun preparePostAsync(callback: (Token) -> Unit) {
    // make request and return immediately 
    // arrange callback to be invoked later
}
```

I would prefer promises to be honest

> **Promises**
>
> The idea behind futures or promises (there are also other terms these
>   can be referred to depending on language/platform), is that when we
>   make a call, we're promised that at some point it will return with an
>   object called a Promise, which can then be operated on.

```
fun postItem(item: Item) {
    preparePostAsync() 
        .thenCompose { token -> 
            submitPostAsync(token, item)
        }
        .thenAccept { post -> 
            processPost(post)
        }

}

fun preparePostAsync(): Promise<Token> {
    // makes request an returns a promise that is completed later
    return promise 
}
```

Do your work and when the promise is fullfilled, proceed to data validation.

You can read more about coroutines [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/coroutines/async-programming.html)

Comment: Hi George, thanks for your reply!
For another project I followed exactly the last example of the read on coroutines and it worked fine!
Is there any way to make it work in this case too or you think it's better to give a try with promises?

Comment: I would go with promises. As you said on your edit you're waiting for the function to be fulfilled in order to proceed with the generated data. Have a look on the answer above but I'm pretty sure promises will make your life easier on this one